# import a sqlite script to create a database in c# and t

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm creating a c# console app and using **sqlite as my db**, and I have two scripts the first script (DBCreationScript.sql) contains the database schema(tables to be created) and the second script (DefaultData.sql) populates the database tables with default data.
Is there a way or specific code that I could use to load/import/run the two scripts in my console application.

My goal is to :
1. Create the sqlite db (by loading the script) using code from my console app.
2. Populate the database (by loading the second script).
3. Then query the data and display on the console screen

see below the two scripts.

```html
CREATE TABLE tbLocation
(
    LocationCd   varchar(3) PRIMARY KEY
    ,LocationName  varchar(50)
    ,CountryCd   varchar(2) REFERENCES tbCountry(CountryCd)
    ,CountryName        varchar(25)
    ,PassportRequired bit
    ,SortOrder   Integer
);

CREATE TABLE tbManage
(
    ConfigParamCd  varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY
    ,ConfigParamDesc varchar(225)
    ,ConfigParamTypeCd varchar(20)
    ,Value    varchar(2000)
    ,[Status]   bit
);

CREATE TABLE tbPerson
(
    PersonNo     varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY
    ,FirstName   varchar(25)
    ,LastName   varchar(25)
    ,PinCode   varchar(5)
    ,FleetCd   varchar(10)
    ,[Status]   bit
);
```

.

```html
INSERT INTO tbManage (ConfigParamCd,ConfigParamDesc,ConfigParamTypeCd,Value,Status)
select 'AirlineCd' ConfigParamCd, 'The current airline code.' ConfigParamDesc, 'String' ConfigParamTypeCd, 'BA' Value, '1' Status UNION
select 'CanCreateNewSector' ConfigParamCd, 'Does this airline allow crew members to create new sectors?' ConfigParamDesc, 'Boolean' ConfigParamTypeCd, '1' Value, '1' Status UNION
select 'CanEditSeals' ConfigParamCd, 'Does this airline allow crew members to add, edit or delete seals?' ConfigParamDesc, 'Boolean' ConfigParamTypeCd, '1' Value, '1' Status UNION
select 'CanSectorsReopen' ConfigParamCd, 'Does this airline allow crew members to reopen sectors?' ConfigParamDesc, 'Boolean' ConfigParamTypeCd, '1' Value, '1' Status UNION
select 'DefaultCurrency' ConfigParamCd, 'The default currency code.' ConfigParamDesc, 'String' ConfigParamTypeCd, 'ZAR' Value, '1' Status UNION
select 'DefaultCurrencySymbol' ConfigParamCd, 'The default currency symbol.' ConfigParamDesc, 'String' ConfigParamTypeCd, 'R' Value, '1' Status UNION
select 'EmergencyNumber' ConfigParamCd, 'The emergency number of the airline.' ConfigParamDesc, 'String' ConfigParamTypeCd, '911' Value, '1' Status UNION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a db script consisting of DDL and DML first and call, SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(string databaseFileName) method. Specify IF NOT EXISTS in the CREATE statement.

Comment: Thanks!!! I have used  SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(DBCreationpath) where the path represented the relative path of the Sqlite db. and it worked :)